# Do switches modify frames as they pass through?

Tags: router, switch

I'm new to networking and was wondering if switches modify frames as they pass through?

I've heard that routers modify the contents of their packets as they pass through (which I believe is true), but I can't find a concrete answer about what modifications switches make to the frames that pass through it, if any.

Help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I could swear this has been asked before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, *layer-2* switching does not modify the frames.<sup>[1]</sup> A VLAN tag may be added or removed as necessary for frames between tagged and untagged ports.

A *layer-3* switch is both a router (l3) and switch (l2). When it switches traffic, it's just like any other layer-2 switch. When it routes traffic between segments, then it's routing and will modify packets like any router (namely decrement ttl.)

<sup>[1] Not to confuse matters, but "carrier ethernet" hardware can do VLAN translation, which does, technically, modify frames.</sup>

Comment: Tagging/untagging a frame would change the checksum also.

Comment: The FCS lives as "layer-1" and isn't something any NIC (or OS) ever (normally) passes around; much like the preamble, inter packet gap, etc., they aren't something the OS or driver deals with; it's handled by the layer-1 interface of the NIC chipset. (ethernet diagnostic hardware uses chips that can be set to a "raw" mode so they can see *everything*; errors and all.)

Comment: Also worth noting that like any other router it will strip the src/dst mac address and replace the source with its own mac addr and the dst with the mac addr of the destination host or next hop.